# Sending more than one array to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

im trying to send more than one array to my jquery ajax

the arrays were made like this

```
var i = 0;
    var tname = [];
    var tid = [];
    var tprice = [];

    $(".party_list li").each(function() {
        tname[i] = $(this).data('catname');
        tid[i] = $(this).data('catid');
        tprice[i] = $(this).data('price');
    i++;    
    });
```

and is sent to my jquery ajax like this

```
var table_data = 'tname='+tname + '&tid='+tid + '&tprice='+tprice;

$.ajax({
    url:base+'site/store_tabledata',
    type:'POST',
    data:table_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response2){
    console.log(response2.name);
        $('#planner').load(base+"site/table_planner");
    }

    });
```

when i try to loop the contents of these arrays in my

```
 $('#planner').load(base+"site/table_planner);
```

it says something like

> an invalid argument supplied foreach()

is there a way to send array variables to ajax?

Comment: Forgot to close the quote: `$('#planner').load(base + "site/table_planner");` should do the trick.

Comment: sorry i accidentally deleted the close quote while editing my post but the original has a close quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try sending it as object..

```
var table_data = {'tname':tname,'tid':tid,'tprice':tprice};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your data variable you can't pass string, instead try the following:

```
data: { tname: tname, tid: tid, tprice : tprice  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
data: { product: JSON.stringify( your_array_of_objects ) }
```